# How to identify moderators in Data SE queries?

Tags: support, data-explorer, moderators

As I can see, the Data SE doesn't contain data, who are/were the moderator currently, or in the past.

To some queries, I would like to use this data. Currently, I do this by checking the election pages manually to identify the moderatorship start dates. I check manually the review log of the ex-mods (on their user page) to identify the end dates of their mod time interval.

But, and automatized solution could be more useful.

My current best idea is to search for close/reopen `PostHistory` events where he was the only voter. The MIN and MAX of the CreationDate columns would be a rough estimation of the start/end dates.

Does a better way for the task exist?

Comment: A related "side-question" would be: *"Did it happen in the history of the SE that a moderator was de-modded, and then he became later a mod again?"* I am not sure, it should be a different question or not. If the accepted answer to this question contains this information, I will extend this question accordingly; if not, I will post a new one.

Comment: I don't think SE would let someone run in an election if they had been removed as a moderator in the past.

Comment: @yannis I think it depends largely on the circumstances of his removal. What if he resigned on personal reasons, and years later he would nominate on a new election again? I wouldn't close out that this could be allowed by the SE. Although also I didn't ever see a single duplication on the election pages on any sites.

Comment: Ah, I assumed by "de-modded" you meant asked to resign. But sure, it's possible that someone who stepped down voluntarily may be interested in running in a future election. It hasn't happened yet (as far as I know), but it's possible.

Comment: @yannis I would like to process some data of mod activity, thus what really counts for me, is only the begin and end time of their mod interval. The reason of the de-modding is not. If it is possible to have mods with *multiple* mod intervals, it makes my task much harder. Furthermore, short demoddings (for example, until the mod talked with the responsible CM that he wasn't really soo bad and he accepted the explanation) probably happened, but they were short and thus they aren't important.

Comment: Yeah... it's annoying that this data isn't present. Your current best is really similar to *my* current best, the workaround in the linked dupe. So far I haven't found anything better. *Grumble...*

Comment: @JasonC Yes, but unfortunately also golden tag badge owners can produce decisive vtc/vtr votes, and they are in overlap with the moderators... maybe the delete/undelete events could be more useful - here only the "delete by owner" confuses the picture, but not heavily.

Comment: @peterh See the workaround. Mine was based on PostNotices, looking for non-bounty notices, which only mods and CMs can post.

Comment: @JasonC Ok, thanks! The SE employee still confuse, but they aren't too many to be not filtered out by hardcoded values. Maybe the election page data could be used to filter out them automatically, but also this is not perfect (for example, animuson has won an election and later became SE employee).